# DXF attribute to z value

Tags: 3d, ogr, fme-form, dxf

We have been given a DXF that contains a Elevation attribute but we would like to generate a 3D DXF.  I know I can generate a 3D dxf from a shapefile using:

```
ogr2ogr -f "DXF" out.dxf in.shp -zfield Elev
```

But the ogr driver doesn't seem to pick up the attributes as fields in the dxf.

Does anyone know if this is possible.

I would like a free solution if possible.  We do have FME but I'm looking around for other options.

Comment: not sure what you mean by elev attribute. is it a block definition with attributes?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for polygons as it creates hatches which don't have elevatuion. Adding parameter `-nlt MULTILINESTRING` to ogr2ogr fixed this for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been trying to find a way of doing this for months. In the end, the only method I could find was to load the DXF into gvSIG and export it as a shapefile. Doing this adds the linestring z-value to the shapefile's DBF as an attribute.

In my case, the DXFs were OS OpenData containing contours, along with other data that I did not require, so I extracted just the contours to a new DXF before loading the file into gvSIG:

```
ogr2ogr -f DXF contours.dxf -where "LAYER='G8040201'" original.dxf
```

Answer (score 2):

In FME you would want the [3DForcer](http://www.fmepedia.com/index.php/3DForcer) transformer.

Comment: This is the route I would do - though the question sways for a cheaper (i.e. free) solution.