# Exporting QGIS contour attributes in DXF file?

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, contour, dxf, autodesk

I have a .tiff data file that generates contours in QGIS. I save it as .dxf. The contours don't have any attributes or data. That's bad, because I want to make a 3D landscape in Revit using the information.

How do a save/export the contour lines from QGIS so that they have a z-elevation attribute or at least some information?

---

I ticked the attributes box when extracting the contours, but the attributes doesn't show in the dxf.

Comment: Note that my answer was revised to address missing attributes. If that (or any other) answer solves your problem, please mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 6):

When you generate the contours in QGIS, make sure that you tick the `Attribute name` box.  Then when you ogr2ogr (you must use command line - this is not an option in QGIS Save AS), specify the zfield.  For example, if your elevation attribute is "ELEV", then your command could look something this:

```
ogr2ogr -f "DXF" contours-out.dxf contours.shp -zfield ELEV
```

By the way, if you were searching for this in answers, you would not have found it.  I learned this method from [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12937/dxf-attribute-to-z-value).

EDIT: I should also point  out that the DXF will not have an attribute field for elevation, but instead will be drawn to elevation.

Comment: ogr2ogr? I am on a mac..

Comment: Well, that would be another question. It's well documented. You're looking for the GDAL command line utilities.

Comment: I was really surprised to find out that this is the only way which worked for me. Though the command itself comes naturally with errors it can't create fields, the final DXF is 3D when tested in Autodesk TrueView.