# QGIS: exporting contours to DXF with height values

Tags: qgis, dxf, noise

I am using this video tutorial to create ground contours for a noise model in iNoise.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JxCxBREEqG0

See tutorial 8 https://dgmrsoftware.com/products/inoise/gallery/

When I import the dxf file it has no height data.  Not sure where I'm going wrong as all the layers have height data when checked in QGIS.

It seems I lose it when exporting as a DXF.

This question may indicate that DXF has no height values but is drawn to height.  Not sure.

[Exporting QGIS contour attributes in DXF file?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/84152/exporting-qgis-contour-attributes-in-dxf-file)

Comment: Currently there's the [to-be-fixed issue](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/34156) that QGIS doesn't export attributes when exporting to DXF. So... you need a work around. What are you going to do with the dxf-file?

Comment: I import the dxf into iNoise (noise modelling program) as height lines to create the terrain.

Answer (score 4):

Try using the `Set Z value` tool in `Processing Toolbox > Vector geomoetry` instead of Grass.

Use the icon to the right of the Z Value input and click Edit to add an expression. For the expression just write `"ELEV"`.

Then when you are exporting the layer to DXF make sure the `Include z-dimension` box is checked, if it isn't then set the `Geometry type` to LineString and then check the box.